# Convert a Bibtex class object to a series of text strings formatted for each citation

Tags: r, bibtex

I'm new to bibTex objects, and want to generate a list of text strings for each citation in the object as a formatted citation. I don't want to generate a document--these strings will be used for a downstream purpose within R. Is there a way to do this? I can't even really figure out how to access the pieces of each citation in a bibTex object.

Put another way, how to I turn this:

```
   temp <- toBibtex(c(citation("base"), citation("sp")))
```

into this:

```
  [[1]]
  [1] "R Core Team (2019). R: A language and environment for statistical computing. R Foundation for Statistical Computing, Vienna, Austria. https://www.R-project.org/."

  [[2]]
  [1] "Pebesma, E.J., R.S. Bivand (2005). Classes and methods for spatial data in R. R News 5. https://cran.r-project.org/doc/Rnews/."

  [[3]]
  [1] "Bivand, R.S., Pebesma, E.J., Gomez-Rubio, V. (2013). Applied spatial data analysis with R, Second edition. Springer, NY. https://asdar-book.org/."
```

Help?

Comment: Thanks to both @zx8754 and @agila for your answers. Both are perfectly appropriate and workable. In this case, I went with the @zx8754 because I wanted more control over the formatting of the citation than `$textVersion` gives me. I really like the control `bib2df()` gives you over formatting, I just wish I didn't have to write a .bib file to disk first. Ah, well.

Comment: Added a bit more from RefmanageR package, I think that is the package you need to explore, it doesn't require reading from bib file, see my answer for example.

Comment: Another follow-up to this saga--apparently `bibtex` is orphaned and has been archived, and `RefManageR` is on the way to a similar fate. Back to the drawing board!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using *bib2df* package:

```
library(bibtex)
library(bib2df)

write.bib(c("base", "sp"), "temp.bib")

x <- bib2df("temp.bib")

apply(x, 1, function(i){
  paste(
    #adding authors and titles
    paste(unlist(i$AUTHOR), collapse = ", "),
    i$TITLE,
    # add other bits here as needed
    sep = ", ")
})

# [1] "R Core Team, R: A Language and Environment for Statistical Computing"                                        
# [2] "Edzer J. Pebesma, Roger S. Bivand, Classes and methods for spatial data in {R"                               
# [3] "Roger S. Bivand, Edzer Pebesma, Virgilio Gomez-Rubio, Applied spatial data analysis with {R}, Second edition"
```

Note: I am new to bibtex, too. There is also *RefManageR* package, might be more useful.

---

Using *RefManageR*:

```
library(RefManageR)

# read bib file
x1 <- ReadBib("temp.bib")
# or convert citations to bibentry object
x2 <- as.BibEntry(c(citation("base"), citation("sp")))
```

Both will print as below:

```
# [1] R. S. Bivand, E. Pebesma, and V. Gomez-Rubio. _Applied spatial data analysis with R, Second
# edition_. Springer, NY, 2013. <URL: https://asdar-book.org/>.
# 
# [2] E. J. Pebesma and R. S. Bivand. “Classes and methods for spatial data in R”. In: _R News_ 5.2 (Nov.
#                                                                                                    2005), pp. 9-13. <URL: https://CRAN.R-project.org/doc/Rnews/>.
# [3] R Core Team. _R: A Language and Environment for Statistical Computing_. R Foundation for
# Statistical Computing. Vienna, Austria, 2019. <URL: https://www.R-project.org/>.
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can apply something like the following code:

```r
pkgs <- c("base", "sp")
lapply(pkgs, function(x) citation(x)$textVersion)
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "R Core Team (2020). R: A language and environment for statistical computing. R Foundation for Statistical Computing, Vienna, Austria. URL https://www.R-project.org/."
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [[2]][[1]]
#> [1] "Pebesma, E.J., R.S. Bivand, 2005. Classes and methods for spatial data in R. R News 5 (2), https://cran.r-project.org/doc/Rnews/."
#> 
#> [[2]][[2]]
#> [1] "Roger S. Bivand, Edzer Pebesma, Virgilio Gomez-Rubio, 2013. Applied spatial data analysis with R, Second edition. Springer, NY. https://asdar-book.org/"
```

or, if you need precisely 1 reference per each element of the list, I think you can run:

```
as.list(unlist(lapply(pkgs, function(x) citation(x)$textVersion)))
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "R Core Team (2020). R: A language and environment for statistical computing. R Foundation for Statistical Computing, Vienna, Austria. URL https://www.R-project.org/."
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] "Pebesma, E.J., R.S. Bivand, 2005. Classes and methods for spatial data in R. R News 5 (2), https://cran.r-project.org/doc/Rnews/."
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] "Roger S. Bivand, Edzer Pebesma, Virgilio Gomez-Rubio, 2013. Applied spatial data analysis with R, Second edition. Springer, NY. https://asdar-book.org/"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-09-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Not necessarily `bib` objects specifically, but there is a fair amount of variance in the format of the `$textVersion` citations. I want to be able to reformat the citations to make them uniform.